# Basic operations on Simple Triplet Matrix (Document Term Matrix)

Tags: r, matrix, tm

I am struggling to understand how to do basic operations with Simple Triplet Matrix produced by `TermDocumentMatrix()` of the `tm` package.

It seems that the problem could be with the matrices not being recognized as numeric.

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)

vector <- tdm[,1]
matrix <- tdm[,2:20]

multiplication <- t(vector) %*% matrix

# Error in t(vector) %*% matrix : 
#   requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

But

```
multiplication <- t(as.matrix(vector)) %*% as.matrix(matrix)
multiplication
# Docs
# Docs  144 191 194 211 236 237 242 246 248 273 349 352 353 368 489 502 543 704 708
# 127 232  56  62  65 201 214  61 159 244 197  51  90  71  84  96 126  90 152  11
```

I have a very large Term Document Matrix which doesn't allow me to transform the sparse matrix into a dense matrix with as.matrix().

Is there any way to operate directly on the Simple Triplet Matrix without applying transformation into different classes (like `sparseMatrix()` of the Matrix package)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `slam` package has methods for simple triplet matrices:

```
library(slam)

matprod_simple_triplet_matrix(t(v), m)
```

Or equivalently:

```
crossprod_simple_triplet_matrix(v, m)
```